# For two square positive-semidefinite matrices $A$ and $B$, does the relation $|A|^{-\frac{1}{2}}|B|^{-\frac{1}{2}} = |AB|^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For two square positive-semidefinite matrices $A$ and $B$, does the relation $|A|^{-\frac{1}{2}}|B|^{-\frac{1}{2}} = |AB|^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ hold? Here the absolute value signs are the determinant operator, $|\cdot|$. Thank you.

Comment: If it is only semidefinite it might not be invertible and its determinant may be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, we have $|AB|=|A||B|$.

Hence we have reduce the problem to for  $x,y\geq0$, does the relation $x^{-\frac12}y^{-\frac12}=(xy)^{-\frac12}$ hold?